# Only install to custom folder

Tags: maven, multi-module

I have a multimodule project in maven. I want the modules to be installed in the repository location I want. I want to also keep outside generated dependencies in the main .m2 folder.

Then my idea is to use something like this to include my project generated dependencies.

```
<repositories>
    <!--other repositories if any-->
    <repository>
        <id>project.local</id>
        <name>project</name>
       <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

I have tried `maven-install-plugin` but it installs my generated modules to both the main local and the project repo.

Can you give me any advice on how to do so?

Edit: Include maven-install-plugin configuration that is not working properly as it installs in both local and project repository

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install-jar-lib</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <configuration>
              <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</file>
              <generatePom>false</generatePom>
              <pomFile>pom.xml</pomFile>
              <packaging>jar</packaging>
              <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
              <skip>true</skip>
              <localRepositoryPath>./mylocalrepo</localRepositoryPath>    
            </configuration>    
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Advice: don't do anything like this. Stick with conventional project layouts and conventional library use. Do not step outside convention at all costs. Your life will be a lot easier if you stick to using things normally. The weirder you make things, the less help and support you'll get and you may as well start using 'gradle'.

Comment: First what is the problem with installing artifacts in `$HOME/.m2/repository` ? What kind of problem are you really trying solving...

Comment: I wanted to have things a little more in order. This way my packages are in each project and is easier to delete, modify, etc. without touching the main one. Anyway from what you say, it seems it is not sensible

Comment: A repository in Maven is ordered by using groupId/artifactId/version coordinates which is represented by directories. The location in `$HOME/.m2/repository` in only a local cache. So the question is: Why do you need to delete things there ? Furthermore having a configuration of maven-install-plugin in your build are you mentioned there is definitively something wrong in your build...For a multi module build you usually go on the root level and do a `mvn clean package` and usually there is no need to do a `mvn clean install` cause module inter dependencies will be solved by Maven...